# How to call absoluteURL() when adding OpenID support to a Play Framework application?

Tags: java, openid, playframework-2.0

I am attempting to add OpenID login support to a Play Framework application using the sample code on [the documentation page](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaOpenID):

```
Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
attributes.put("email", "http://schema.openid.net/contact/email");
OpenID.redirectURL(
  openid, 
  routes.Application.openIDCallback.absoluteURL(), 
  attributes
);
```

The problem is that when I use this code, I get the following compilation error:

```
cannot find symbol [symbol: method absoluteURL()] [location: class play.api.mvc.Call]
```

Indeed, there isn't a no-argument `absoluteURL()` method of the [`Call`](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/java/play/mvc/Call.html) class; the Call#absoluteURL() methods are:

```
absoluteURL(Http.Request request)
```

and:

```
absoluteURL(Http.Request request, boolean secure)
```

What `Http.Request` instance do I need to use? What is the significance of the `secure` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the current request:

```
Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
attributes.put("email", "http://schema.openid.net/contact/email");
OpenID.redirectURL(
  openid, 
  routes.Application.openIDCallback.absoluteURL(request()), 
  attributes
);
```

Comment: This seems to work. Do you know why the current request has to be passed in?

Comment: Maybe to pass the original request headers (Accept, language etc...) to the final request.